# python loop optimisation on lists

Tags: python-3.x, loops, optimization

I have the following loop:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for x in tqdm(data):

    min_distance = [maxsize, 0]
    for i, y in enumerate(data2):
        distance = haversine(float(y[0]),float(y[1]),float(x[10]),float(x[11]))
        if distance < min_distance[0]:
            min_distance = [distance, i]
    x.append(min_distance[1])
```

data is a list of length 18,000 and data2 is a list of length 800,000, the loop goes through each latitude, longitude in data, calculate distance between that point and all points in data2 (so one point in data vs 800,000 points in data2 per iteration of loop) using the haversine formula defined earlier in the script and appends the index of the coordinates in data2 where the minimum distance occurs.

The issue I have is that by using tqdm, I can track where the loop is up to and the estimated time of completion and I am getting about 15 hours to complete the loop. I'm fairly new at programming in general and wanted to know if there would be any methods to make the code run faster?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Divide up all the `data2` points into a grid - perhaps 10° square.  Initially search only the grid square containing the `data` point, which will be 1/648 of the work you're currently doing.  Only search additional grid squares if nothing has been found, or the point is close enough to the edge of the searched area that there could be a closer match in an adjacent square.

Comment: Can you post definition for `haversine()` and a sample input and output as well? Thanks.